# What is the difference between Axiom and Variable in Coq

Tags: coq, theorem-proving

In Coq I can write

```
Variable A : False.
Axiom B : False.
```

which assume `False` under names `A` and `B`. Both statements work in proofs, so I can

```
Theorem nothing_makes_sense : forall (a : Type), a.
  destruct true; exfalso.
  * apply A.
  * apply B.
Qed.
```

What is the actual difference? When should I use one instead of another?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is advised to use the commands Axiom, Conjecture and Hypothesis (and their plural forms) for logical postulates (i.e. when the assertion type is of sort Prop), and to use the commands Parameter and Variable (and their plural forms) in other cases (corresponding to the declaration of an abstract mathematical entity).

And as you can see in the specification of coq https://coq.inria.fr/refman/coq-cmdindex.html they are defined in the same way.